# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFBoolean' (0x100b123b8) to 'NSString' (0x100f0ab48)

Tags: ios, json, string, swift, boolean

I'm trying to parse a .json file, but as I thought I was near the end, an error occurred:

Could not cast value of type '__NSCFBoolean' (0x10c8ba3b8) to 'NSString' (0x10ccb2b48).

I have done my research and I found to (surprise) that i have some Boolean values messing around in stade of String in my .json ...

So how can I avoid this? I've looked up for some method which could give me the type of the bar["tags"] before I try to put it in a String but I can't find..

Here is an extract of the .json and my (much too long) code:

```
...{
    "id": 3906,
    "address": "L\u2019Hotel le 123 Sebastopol 23, boulevard S\u00e9bastopol, Paris, 75002, Le Louvre, Paris",
    "name": "123 Sebastopol",
    "url": "/bar/paris/le-louvre/123-sebastopol",
    "image_url": "https://prh-wbb-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/generic_640_480/WBB%20holding%20image3_54abcf7d218d1_55b8d2128eabb.jpg",
    "tags": "Hotel, Cocktail, Terrace",
    "latitude": 48.867598851356,
    "longitude": 2.3533117460327
}, {
    "id": 1523,
    "address": "73 Rue d\u0027Aboukir, 75002 Paris, France, Le Louvre, Paris",
    "name": "Lockwood",
    "url": "/bar/paris/le-louvre/lockwood",
    "image_url": "https://prh-wbb-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/bar_640_480/lockwood_001_553f5b2c99f4b.jpg",
    "tags": false,
    "latitude": 48.867716087563,
    "longitude": 2.3469846706722
}...
```

my code:

```
id = (bar["id"] as? Int)!
name = (bar["name"] as? String)!
adress = (bar["address"] as? String)!
url = (bar["url"] as? String)!
image_url = (bar["image_url"] as? String)!

tags = (bar["tags"] as? String)!

latitude = (bar["latitude"] as? Double)!
longitude = (bar["longitude"] as? Double)!
```

Comment: In your JSON `"tags": false,`. This is is causing the error.

Comment: your first stub shows **tags** as string and second shows it as bool. that is the cause of error.

Comment: this line provoc the error
    tags = (bar["tags"] as? String)!

the "tags" is supposed to be a String (200/208) so I just want to replace the false by an empty String

Answer (score 2):

hum, seem's like I didn't do enough research!

here is the solution:

```
if let test = bar["tags"] as? String {
    tags = (bar["tags"] as? String)!
}else{
    tags=" "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once I resolved to parse JSON under Swift3 and did not expect the result to be a Bool.

Here is my code in the hope it helps folk like me who are not fans of Swift 3.

In my case the entry in the JSON output was

```
success = 0;
```

note it did not have the **""** around **success** or **0** like this

```
"success" = "0"
```

So here is the code I used to obtain the Bool value from the JSON output

```
success = 0
```

Noting no " "

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
if (jsonResult?["success"] as? Bool)!
 {
      okToLogIn = true
      print(okToLogIn)
 }
 else
 {
       okToLogIn = false
       print(okToLogIn)
 }
```

So I just kept it as Bool and checked against true or false and my code now works as it should.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to parse treat `Bool` value - false - as instance of `String`.

Change your code to:

```
id = (bar["id"] as? Int)!
name = (bar["name"] as? String)!
adress = (bar["address"] as? String)!
url = (bar["url"] as? String)!
image_url = (bar["image_url"] as? String)!

tags = (bar["tags"] as? Bool)!

latitude = (bar["latitude"] as? Double)!
longitude = (bar["longitude"] as? Double)!
```